# Вывод картинки из БД формата Blob в React

Tags: sql, reactjs, blob

Есть в бд картинка типа blob, получаю их на реакте в таком виде[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне ее вывести на реакте? что необходимо проделать?
Пробовал так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не один способ не работает...подскажите как и что делать?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.state.articleImage)]));
reader.onloadend = function() {
var base64data = reader.result;
console.log(base64data);
}

-----

let data = this.state.articleImage;
console.log(data);
let buff = new Buffer(data);
console.log(buff);
let base64data1 = buff.toString('base64');
console.log(base64data1);
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, тут вроде бы все должно работать, дополним ваш код тем, что сохраним  вашу переменную `base64Data` в стейт, она нам будет нужна для рендера, вот так (я надеюсь, что этот блок кода находится внутри `componentDidMount` метода):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.state.articleImage)]));
reader.onloadend = function() {
  var base64data = reader.result;
  this.setState({ base64ImageData: base64data })
}
```

Ну а потом, уже в самом методе рендеринга (наш `render` метод компонента) сделаем следующее (не знаю, в каком именно месте, в вашей разметке это будет):

```
<img src={"data:image/jpeg;" + this.state.base64ImageData} />
```

Да, тут есть небольшой нюанс в типе картинки... Также, нужно проверить, что полученная `base64ImageData` переменная начинается с `base64,`, если этого нет, то это нужно вставить в данные вот так: `"data:image/jpeg;base64,"` а потом уже будут идти данные картинки.

В общем вот пример кода:

```js
// Base64 encoded image
const imageBase64 = "base64,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";

class Example extends React.Component{
    
    render() {
        return <img src={"data:image/jpeg;" + imageBase64} />
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

И ссылка на источник: [How to display image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399865/5275890)